# android - RAM consumption increases while overwriting large objects

Tags: android, performance, android-memory

*To the downvoters: I'm not pasting any code since my question is generalized, I'll post some as soon as someone request it.*

In my application I load a user's playlist in form of quite a large `JSONArray` on Activity's start, parse and display this data in a `ListView`. If the user presses the Update button the whole operation gets repeated, same objects get overwritten. I noticed that the RAM amount used by the app gets increased randomly between 0.4 and 1 MB with each update. I'm trying to figure out the reason, the same memory addresses just get overwritten with new data, why does the RAM consumption grow? I also tried to set all used objets to `null` before doing the update, this decreased the RAM amount used but only by about 100KB.

I have no explanation for that issue, since there're same variables which just get overwritten. *The size of server response has not changed.*  Any ideas how to fix this memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the same memory addresses don't get overwritten.  You're creating new objects that take up new memory, and both copies will stick around until the old one is garbage collected.  You can speed that along by making sure there's no dangling references to the old data anywhere in the app (by explicitly setting them to null), or by calling System.gc (although that has large negative penalties to it).  But growing in that situation is expected.  What shouldn't be happening is that if you do an hprof after getting the result several times you should never see the total number of instances of your array increasing unbounded.  If you do, then you need to track up the chain of owners and see who's still hanging on.